# Is it possible to mock services AFTER creation of WebApplicationFactory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mocking, integration-testing, moq

I have an IntegrationTestHelper class, which I use to create a WebApplicationFactory with mocked InMemory db.

```
public class IntegrationTestHelper
{
    public WebApplicationFactory<RentAPI.Program> GetWebApplicationFactory(string databaseName)
    {
        var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<RentAPI.Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                var dbContextDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d =>
                    d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>));

                services.Remove(dbContextDescriptor);

                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName);
                });
            });
        });

        using var scope = factory.Services.CreateScope(); ;
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
        var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

        SeedData(userManager, roleManager, db).Wait();

        return factory;
    }
    ...
}
```

I use GetWebApplicationFactory in next test to get WebApplicationFactory instanse and then use WithWebHostBuilder one more time to mock IFileStorageService, but it doesn't work. API continues to use the implementation for IFileStorageService added in Program.cs.

```
public class PropertyControllerTests
{
    private IntegrationTestHelper _helper;
    private WebApplicationFactory<RentAPI.Program> _factory;
    private HttpClient _client;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _helper = new IntegrationTestHelper();
        _factory = _helper.GetWebApplicationFactory(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }

    #region AddNewProperty
    [Test]
    public async Task AddNewProperty_ReturnsOk()
    {
        // Arrange
        _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                var fileStorageService = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IFileStorageService));
                services.Remove(fileStorageService);

                var mockedService = new Mock<IFileStorageService>();
                mockedService.Setup(_ => _.UploadFilesAsync(It.IsAny<IFormFile[]>()))
                    .ReturnsAsync(new List<string> { "fileId1", "fileId2" });
                services.AddScoped(_ => mockedService.Object);
            });
        });
        _client = _factory.CreateClient();

        ... // creating and setting data in content

        // Act
        var response = await _client.PostAsync("property/landlord/add", content);

        // Assert
        Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _client.Dispose();
        _factory.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But when I moved

```
var fileStorageService = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IFileStorageService));
services.Remove(fileStorageService);

var mockedService = new Mock<IFileStorageService>();
mockedService.Setup(_ => _.UploadFilesAsync(It.IsAny<IFormFile[]>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(new List<string> { "fileId1", "fileId2" });
services.AddScoped(_ => mockedService.Object);
```

to GetWebApplicationFactory everything started working. It looks like this

```
public WebApplicationFactory<RentAPI.Program> GetWebApplicationFactory(string databaseName)
{
    var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<RentAPI.Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            var dbContextDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d =>
                d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>));

            services.Remove(dbContextDescriptor);

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName);
            });

            var fileStorageService = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IFileStorageService));
            services.Remove(fileStorageService);

            var mockedService = new Mock<IFileStorageService>();
            mockedService.Setup(_ => _.UploadFilesAsync(It.IsAny<IFormFile[]>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(new List<string> { "fileId1", "fileId2" });
            services.AddScoped(_ => mockedService.Object);
        });
    });

    using var scope = factory.Services.CreateScope(); ;
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
    var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

    SeedData(userManager, roleManager, db).Wait();

    return factory;
}
```

It works, but for me this implementation is not convenient.

So is it possible to mock services after creation of WebApplicationFactory?

Answer (score 0):

If you check `WithWebHostBuilderCore` you will see that it returns `WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint>` which your completely ignore. Try using it:

```
var newFactory = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
{
    //..
});
// I would recommend to avoid assigning to shared fields in the test
// so the local variable usage
var client = newFactory.CreateClient();
```

As for "original" `_factory` - `factory.Services` (called for seeding) will initialize the test server internally which requires building service provider from service collection and default service provider is basically read-only from registration point of view (i.e. you can't add/remove registrations).